# Java - Repeated word count in the large file

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to find the repeated word count from the large file content. Is there any best approach using java 8 stream API?

Updated Details

File format is comma separated values and the file size is around 4 GB

Comment: What is your file format? And repeated word count, it that simply for each word in the input, a count of occurrences? Or…?

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know if there’s a best approach, and it would also depend on the details you haven’t told us. For now I am assuming a text file with a number of words separated by spaces on each line. A possible approach would be:

```
    Map<String, Long> result = Files.lines(filePath)
            .flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split(" ")))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word, Collectors.counting()));
```

I think the splitting of each line into words needs to be refined; you will probably want to discard punctuation, for example. Take this as a starting point and develop it into what you need in your particular situation.

Edit: with thanks to @4castle for the inspiration, the splitting into words can be done in this way of you prefer a method reference over a lambda:

```
    Map<String, Long> result = Files.lines(filePath)
            .flatMap(Pattern.compile(" ")::splitAsStream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(word -> word, Collectors.counting()));
```

It produces the same. Edit2: nonsense about optimization deleted here.

Maybe we shouldn’t go too far here until we know the more exact requirement for delimiting words in each line.

Comment: For starters the split can be `.flatMap(Pattern.compile(" ")::splitAsStream)`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a list of all the words, say `List<String> words` then you can use something like:

```
 Map<String, Integer> counts = words.parallelStream().
            collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
                w -> w, w -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform same operation in different way just count number of words in the file(all words including repetitive words). Then simple add all words to the set(which does not allow duplicate values) collections using stream. Then perform **total word count - size of the set**. So easily you can get the all repetitive word count.

```
Long totalWordCount = Files.lines(filePath)
                  .flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split(" "))).count();

Set<String> uniqueWords = Files.lines(filePath)
                      .flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split(" ")))
                      .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Long repetitiveWordCount = totalWordCount - (long) uniqueWords.size();
```